# Handlers for menu in tray

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to write simplest app on PyQt, but get a little issue: I dont understand why after add handler for "exit" panel, handler didnt work? After click on "Exit" in menu nothing happens. How i can fix this, than when click on "Exit", my app will be closed?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class RightClickMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        iconMenu = QtGui.QMenu.__init__(self, "Edit", parent)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("edit-cut")
        self.addAction(QtGui.QAction(icon, "&Cut", self))

        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("edit-copy")
        self.addAction(QtGui.QAction(icon, "Copy (&X)", self))

        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("edit-paste")
        self.addAction(QtGui.QAction(icon, "&Paste", self))

        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("edit-paste")
        self.addAction(QtGui.QAction(icon, "&Exit", self))
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.exit)

    def exit(self):
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

class LeftClickMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMenu.__init__(self, "File", parent)

        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("document-new")
        self.addAction(QtGui.QAction(icon, "&New", self))

        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("document-open")
        self.addAction(QtGui.QAction(icon, "&Open", self))

        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("document-save")
        self.addAction(QtGui.QAction(icon, "&Save", self))

class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("tray.png"))

        self.right_menu = RightClickMenu()
        self.setContextMenu(self.right_menu)

        self.left_menu = LeftClickMenu()
        self.activated.connect(self.click_trap)

    def click_trap(self, value):
        if value == self.Trigger: #left click!
            self.left_menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

    def welcome(self):
        self.showMessage("Hello", "I should be aware of both buttons")

    def show(self):
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.show(self)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, self.welcome)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    tray = SystemTrayIcon()
    tray.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed this lines

```
self.addAction(QtGui.QAction(icon, "&Exit", self))
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.exit)
```

on

```
action = QtGui.QAction(icon, "&Exit", self)
self.addAction(action)
self.connect(action, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.exit)
```

and all now great works!

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line:

```
self.addAction(QtGui.QAction(icon, "&Exit", self))
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.exit)
```

As:

```
exitAction = QtGui.QAction(icon, "&Exit", self)
self.addAction(exitAction)
exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exit)
```

The problem is that you are connect the `clicked` signal of `QMenu` to the `exit` method. When you click on the action, the action's `triggered` signal is emited not menu's `clicked` because the action is at the top of the menu.